# how to show one fixed Div at bottom behind of another Div reveals on scrolling like parallax

Tags: javascript, css

how to show one fixed div at bottom behind of another Div reveals on scrolling like parallax

https://jsfiddle.net/wa6b645e/

```
<div class="div_1">
<h1>DIV One</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

<p>..more content here..</p>
</div>

<div class="div_2">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

while scrolling div_1 reveals the bottom div_2(this div is fixed at bottom) like parallax. 
Pls help me to find a solution.

Comment: pls check the footer on this site for example: http://www.landmarkhomesusa.com/

Comment: a combination of html, javascript and css is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in pure CSS. I've created my own example, which I think will be more clear for others:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #999;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

footer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

It's important to add

```
position: relative;
```

to the main div. And also set the same value for .main margin-bottom and footer height. Or at least not smaller.

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/paweljanicki/pen/YGWGEx

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a placeholder div between your div 1 and div 2 which is the height and width of the div you want to hide behind div 1 (in this case that would be your div 2 if I understand your question correctly) and set this placeholder's background as transparent.

```
.div_2 {
    height: 200px;
}
.placeholder {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/NahushF/e4e25dga/